# How to select all the columns in oracle group function?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle19c

I have a table like this

```
  CREATE TABLE "FLIGHT" 
   (    "CID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FID" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SOURCE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DESTINATION" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE
   )
```

cid is customer_id and

fid is flight_id

and data is like this on the table

[image]

I need customer_id and the last fight for destination of each customer.

I am getting result but its not perfect

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
         flight a1
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            cid,
            MAX(fid) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY fid DESC) AS flight
        FROM
            flight
        GROUP BY
            cid
    ) a2 ON a1.cid = a2.cid
            AND a1.fid = a2.flight
```

output:

[image]

I need all the columns from the table , but i am getting extra columns such as cid_1 and flight .

how will I remove these extra 2 columns from the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a1.*
FROM
         flight a1
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            cid,
            MAX(fid) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY fid DESC) AS flight
        FROM
            flight
        GROUP BY
            cid
    ) a2 ON a1.cid = a2.cid
            AND a1.fid = a2.flight
```

This should solve your query[image]

Comment: did u know any other method other than analytical functions ? from interview perspective.